# Linq or string filter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need a filter on the string which takes another string as a parameter, scans first string and  removes all appearances of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) which has an overload specifically for this.

```
var newString = oldString.Replace("foo", string.Empty);
```

This takes your oldString, finds all occurrences of "foo" and removes them.

Answer (score 5):

This would work

```
var s = "string";
s = s.Replace("st", string.Empty);
// s == "ring";
```

Is that not correct?

Comment: There is no one parameter overload to `string.Replace`. So it doesn't compile. You need to add a second parameter where you pass the empty string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19s0f3y3.aspx

Comment: +1 man, you rock! Hardly laughed that hard :) (even you got a minor overload issue)

Answer (score 4):

Use extension methods:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{

    public static string RemoveOccurences(this string s, string occurence)
    {

         return s.Replace(occurence, "");    
    }

}
```

usage:

```
string s = "Remove all appearances of this and that and those";
s.RemoveOccurences("th");
```

Comment: Nor sure if this function warrants it's own extension method. I'd rather use `string.Replace` directly.

Comment: Well, that is your choice. There is certainly benefit if you are using it more and more. Remember it is towards fluent API and makes the code more readable.